# Has Sam Harris ever 'sanctified' violence against Muslims?

Tags: religion, islam, violence

**Scenario**

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wotTSRBQLq0), [Chris Hedges](http://www.truthdig.com/staff/chris_hedges) states that [Christopher Hitchens](http://www.vanityfair.com/contributor/christopher-hitchens) and [Sam Harris](http://www.samharris.org/) have 'sanctified' violence against Muslims because [Muslims] are barbaric.

**Question**

Are there any instances that Sam Harris has ever 'sanctified' (as in to entitle to reverence or respect) violence against Muslims?

**Commentary**

I have followed Sam Harris for quite sometime - and perhaps due to a bias - I do not recall such sanctification. I know that Sam Harris disdains religion, especially Islam, but that isn't the same as sanctification.

To be more fair to Chris Hedges, Christopher Hitchens did [openly support](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGJw114OSeM) the invasion of Iraq by US and Coalition forces due to Saddam Hussein breaking UN Resolutions.

Comment: @DJClayworth Chris Hedges didn't use the word "Sanctioned."

Comment: Can you provide a quote of what Chris Hedges is saying?

Comment: I closed this question because I don't think it is clear enough to answer.  Does [this blog post](http://www.samharris.org/blog/item/the-truth-about-violence) 'sanction violence'? It depends what that means.

Comment: technically speaking, you can't "sanction" something unless you have a legal/political power to do so. You can "incite", but not "sanction", if you're a private individual. So the answer is "no".

Comment: Sorry guys, Chris Hedges does indeed use the word "sanctified". He's doing it in the context of comparing Hitchens and Harris with fundamentalist Christian extremists, who have (it is claimed) "sanctified" violence against Muslims by stating it's God's will that it should happen. His claim is that Harris and Hitchens do the same (metaphorically) by stating that violence against Muslims is approved of in their secular religion. Out of context though it's going to come across as weird.

Comment: The change from "sanctioned" to "[sanctified](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sanctified)" better matches the claim, but makes the claim even murkier. Hedges appears to be using a vague metaphor here.

Comment: Harris has a podcast on which he says in virtually every episode that he doesn't sanction violence against all Muslims. So I'd say no.

Comment: @PointlessSpike Plenty of people say they are not things that they actually are.

Comment: @DJClayworth- I've been following him for a while. You will not find an instance of him encouraging violence against non-combatants. His arguments tend to be quite complex, though, so a cursory glance often leads people to misunderstand.